# Scala. Overriding val field causes ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: scala

I have a few dao classes for working with mongoDB.

There is a parent abstract class Dao:

```
abstract class Dao[COLL <: MongoEntity]()(implicit m: Manifest[COLL]) {

  val clazz = m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[COLL]]
  val collection: Imports.MongoCollection = Dao.getCollection(clazz)
  if(readFromReplica) collection.setReadPreference(mongodb.ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred())
}
```

Also an object for it:

```
object Dao {

def getCollection(clazz: Class[_ <: MongoEntity]): MongoCollection = {
    val collection: MongoCollection = MongoCommonObject.getMongoClient(getCollectionNameByEntityClazz(clazz))
    for ((keys,options) <- props.indexes) {
        collection.ensureIndex(keys, options)
    }
    collection
}
```

Also there is a child dao object:

```
object ClientsDao extends Dao[ClientsEntity] {  

  def listAll[T <: ClientsEntity]: List[T] = {
    ...
  }
}
```

At this point everything works fine, but I need to create one more Dao child to work with existed entity but with another mongo collection:

```
object DeactivatedClientsDao extends Dao[ClientsEntity] {
   override val collection: mongodb.casbah.Imports.MongoCollection = MongoCommonObject.getMongoClient("deactivated_clients")
...
}
```

So for this dao object I tried to override collection field because logic from Dao doesn't fit here. But I receive java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and looks like collection field in DeactivatedClientsDao is not set, so it fails at:

```
  if(readFromReplica) collection.setReadPreference(mongodb.ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred())
```

Comment: Make vals in `Dao` `lazy`